# Snowflake - SYSTEM$ABORT_SESSION with non-literal parameter

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run a [SYSTEM$ABORT_SESSION](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_abort_session.html)(it could be `ABORT_TRANSACTION`) with provided parameter that is not literal:

```
SELECT SYSTEM$ABORT_SESSION(CURRENT_SESSION());
-- NULL
-- no effect, current_session() is an example, it could be read from metadata table
```

Similar with variable(no effect):

```
SET session_id = CURRENT_SESSION();

SELECT $session_id;
-- 70000000000

SELECT SYSTEM$ABORT_SESSION($session_id);
-- NULL
```

Next approach is using subquery(here more luck, as error message is more descriptive):

```
SELECT SYSTEM$ABORT_SESSION(s.session_id)
FROM (SELECT CURRENT_SESSION()) AS s(session_id);
-- non-constant input

SELECT SYSTEM$ABORT_SESSION(s.session_id)
FROM (SELECT $session_id) AS s(session_id);
-- non-constant input
```

The final approach, would be using stored procedure(also not possible due to side-effects):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE abort_session(session_id FLOAT)
RETURNS varchar
LANGUAGE javascript
AS
$$
    // same effect regardless of SQL concatenation/parameter binding
    sql = 'SELECT SYSTEM$ABORT_SESSION(' + SESSION_ID + ')';
    var rs = snowflake.execute({ sqlText: sql});

    return 'Done';
$$;

CALL abort_session(CURRENT_SESSION());
-- Execution error in store procedure ABORT_SESSION:
-- SQL compilation error: Query called from a stored procedure contains a function with side effects
-- [SYSTEM$ABORT_SESSION]. At Snowflake.execute, line 3 position 23
```

It seems that the only way is to generate the query with literal, copy-paste and run(but this is the last resort).

Is there any other way to provide the input that could be determined during runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a cast to int needed.

This returns null:

```sql
SELECT SYSTEM$ABORT_SESSION(CURRENT_SESSION());
```

This works as intended:

```sql
SELECT SYSTEM$ABORT_SESSION(CURRENT_SESSION()::int);
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: That was quite surprising, but nice it is so easy to solve. Btw, what is the data type of argument of ABORT_SESSION? Shouldn't there be an implicit conversion during function call?

Comment: I agree that's surprising behavior - I'm not sure of the implementation, but I got there by playing with your well laid out examples.

Comment: I also see you managed to get nice output with new UI. Using Classic UI when session is aborted, you will be immediately logged out :)